# Passing data back to the current page as POST using jquery auto submit on a second page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I have a page which displays data for a given year.

I would like to ask the user a simple question like "what year would you like to see" via a dropdown menu.

The data set (called from a database) is defined by the single variable `$year`.

My current solution is to as the user the question within a form:

```
<form id="year" method="post" action="processing.php">  
    <select name="year" >
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012" selected>2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="View Year" />

</form>
```

The page processing.php has a single hidden field populated by the POST data `$_POST['year']` and automatically submits this back to the original page, which in turn defines the variable $year via the newly received POST data from processing.php

Code on processing.php page:

```
$year=$_POST['year'];

echo '
<div class="hide" >
    <form id="year" method="post" action="original_page.php">
        <input name="year" value="'.$year.'" />
        <input type="submit" onload="submitForm()" />
    </form>
</div>  


<script>
    function submitForm()
    {
     document.year.submit();
    }
</script>
';
```

Question 1:
Is this a sensible way to achieve this, is there something more elegant I could do?

Question 2:
It does not work - the secon page does not forward me back to the first page on load, what have I don wrong in my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The *elegant* method I think you are talking about is called `AJAX`. It will allow you to retrieve the data from the server without the need to switch pages at all.

See this : [Your code implementing AJAX via jQuery $.get](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/s5kmc/1/)

Of course, now your `processing.php` script will need to retrieve the data you want to display and return it in HTML format so that the `$.get` callback can drop it into the **retrieved_contents** div.